# Next.js render video only on desktop: useEffect can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I know there are multiple similar questions here already, but I can't see which asynchronous fix I need to make in order to make this work.

I have a Next.js website where I want to render a video but only when we're on desktop. I don't want the video at all to be there on mobile to save the user from downloading it in the first place, and in order to do that I wrote my own React hook to keep track of the window size.

I can use the `isDesktop` in my code and it all works, and since I am still in development phase I added the window resize listener so I can easily test things by just resizing my window rather than reloading the page each time.

Everything works as expected, except for this dreaded message:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

which is driving me nuts. I have this code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useWindowSize() {
    const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
    const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState<boolean>(false);

    function update() {
        setIsDesktop(window.innerWidth >= 768);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isBrowser) {
            update();
            window.addEventListener('resize', update, false);
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('resize', update, false);
            };
        }
    }, [isBrowser]);

    return { isDesktop };
}
```

and as soon as I comment out the `update` call in the `useEffect`, the message disappears. But then I no longer get the initial state (meaning, it will not render the video on my desktop page until i start resizing the window, and that's not what should happen).

Comment: Try making `isBrowser` a state variable or (if it's constant) a ref. As it is now it gets assigned on every render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are conditionally calling the useEffect cleanup function, it should always be static. Try putting the `isBrowser` condition inside the cleanup function

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isBrowser) {
    update();
    window.addEventListener('resize', update, false);
  }

  return () => {
    isBrowser && window.removeEventListener('resize', update, false);
  };
}, [isBrowser]);
```

Comment: unfortunately the same error persists. as soon as I remove the call to update(); the error is gone.

Comment: @DannyHobo what about if you replace `useEffect` with `useLayoutEffect`?

Comment: Using Layout Effect fixed it, thanks!